# Holocube of Anakin Skywalker winning the Boonta Eve Classic race

Tags: star-wars

In the [Boonta Eve Classic Wookieepedia article](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Boonta_Eve_Classic), it is mentioned that Han and Leia bought a Holocube of Anakin winning the race. In what media does that appear? Is it in the original trilogy, or in some later book or movie? If it is in a movie, does anyone have a clip / screenshot of it?

I'm curious if it is in the original trilogy because that would mean it was planned from the beginning to have this race in the prequels, and am wondering how they would have portrayed Anakin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, not in the movies, It was in the [Tatooine Ghost](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Tatooine_Ghost) novel, published in March 2003.

> Then, under disguises at a local cantina, the Solos attend an auction there in order to retrieve the Killik Twilight. **During the bid, one of the items on sale is a holographic image of the late Anakin Skywalker back in 32 BBY just after he won the Boonta Eve Podrace.**

---

> *Then she came to a single, oversized holocube.*
>
> *The image was of a sandy-haired boy of perhaps nine or ten, standing
>   in front of an old Podracer cockpit with a pair of goggles down around
>   his neck and both arms raised high over his head. The joy in his grin
>   was as contagious as it was innocent-he was clearly pretending he had
>   just won a big race-but that was not what captured Leia's
>   attention.*
>
> *There was something about those eyes that compelled her to stand there
>   and stare, to forget the presence of Han and the vendor and simply
>   look. They were Luke's eyes, Leia realized. They were the same radiant
>   blue, they had the same depth and softness as her brother's, and-most
>   of all-they had a quiet intensity that burned as brightly as the twin
>   suns themselves.*
>
> ...
>
> *The vendor smiled shrewdly. "Of course. But the boy in this cube is no
>   longer a child. It was taken when he won the Boonta Eve Classic, more
>   than forty years ago."*
>
> *"Won it?" Han scoffed. "Look, don't think you're talking to a pair of
>   nerf herders here. Even when Podracing was legal, humans didn't have
>   the reflexes to survive it-much less win, and especially not as kids."*